# Python print("string", end = '') empty output

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
print("Current hand:")
    for i in range (len(hand)):
        print(hand[i], end = '')
```

Output:

```
Current hand:
```

However, if I delete the `, end = ''` part, it will print each element of the list with a newline as per usual:

```
Current hand:
o
u
a
(etc..)
```

Even stranger, if my code looks like this:

```
print("Current hand:")
for i in range (len(hand)):
    print(hand[i], end = '')
    print(i)
```

The output is this:

```
Current hand:
a0
d1
t2
(etc...)
```

Which indicates the compiler knows perfectly well what I'm trying to do - print without newlines.

Lastly, this:

```
print("Current hand: ", end = '')
```

Outputs absolutely nothing, too.

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue; is your program doing something else that delays it from exiting? No matter how little output your program produces, the output should be flushed from the buffer at the end of its run.

Comment: So nothing is printed after _"Current hand:"_ in the first output? Try `sys.stdout.flush()` after your loop.

Comment: Always flush once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your problem.

```
print("Current hand:")
for i in range (len(hand)):
        print(hand[i], end = "")
```

or this

```
print("Current hand:")
for i in range (len(hand)):
        print(hand[i], end = ' ')
```

The default value of end is `\n` meaning that after the `print` statement it will print a new line. So simply stated end is what you want to be printed after the `print` statement has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

why not try:

```
print("Current hand:\t", end='')
    for i in hand:
        print(i, end = '')
```

Comment: Explanation as to why this would fix the OPs problem would be helpful.